# ReactNative Customize markers placed on Mapview

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

I will refer to the markers as the markers placed on the MapView used in react-native-maps module.

Example of default markers can be found at the bottom of the post. Each marker should refer to some building with services, and in this specific example, assume that each marker is pointing to a hospital.

Here are the questions that are ordered based on the expected complexity of the solution.

### 1. Is it possible to customize the appearance of each marker on the map?

---

As you may refer to the image at the bottom of the post, I would like to be able to chance the appearance of each markers placed on the map.

It may be an image, or a custom-made view.

### 2. Is it possible to customize the behaviors of each marker when it is clicked?

---

For example, when the marker is clicked, I would like to 1) retrieve the hospital's information and expected travel time to each hospital, then 2) display those information with a format of custom-made view.

Here is an example of default markers.

[image_default_marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8qFk.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can use the [`image` property](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps#:%7E:text=Rendering%20a%20Marker%20with%20a%20custom%20image) of the `<Marker/>` object to change the icons of your markers. You can put a conditional statement that check the type of icon you will use if you have this information when using a json data.
2. If you are looping through  a json file like my example below, you can use a [`<CallOut />`](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/HEAD/docs/callout.md) object to show your marker's information from the json file. It will automatically fetch the data per each marker created for each coordinate from the json file.

[Sample code](https://snack.expo.dev/r5LK9vbtQ) and code snippet below:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker, Callout } from 'react-native-maps';
import data from './data.json';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
  callout: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 4,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 4,
  },
  title: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 18,
    flex: 1,
  },
});

class MapApp extends Component {
  dragEnded = (e) => {
    console.log("clicked");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 40.756795,
            longitude: -73.954298,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}>
          {data.map((loc) => (
            <Marker
              coordinate={{ latitude: loc.lat, longitude: loc.lng }}
              image={
                loc.type == 'hospital'
                  ? require('./assets/hosp.png')
                  : require('./assets/green.png')
              }
              description={loc.desc}
              draggable
              onDragEnd={this.dragEnded}>
              <Callout tooltip style={styles.callout}>
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>{loc.desc}</Text>
                </View>
              </Callout>
            </Marker>
          ))}
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MapApp;
```

---

**data.json**

```
[{
  "desc": "This is Hospital",
  "lat":40.756795,
  "lng":-73.954298,
  "type":"hospital"
},
{
  "desc": "This is Green House",
  "lat":40.753167,
  "lng":-73.968120,
  "type":"green"
}]
```